# Регулярное выражение найти в ссылках bbcode домен сайта PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть задача: на форуме phpBB используются ббкоды вида

```
[url=http://someurl.ru]some text[/url]
```

Есть также стандартная регулярка, которая преобразовывает ббкоды в ссылки

```
<a href= ...

$ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#is", "\\1<a href=\"\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
```

Хочу все внешние ссылки перенаправлять на внутреннюю страницу, которая уже будет делать перенаправление во внешний источник и поставить там `nowollow`. Но регулярки нахрапом не осилила.

Не смогла не только изменить стандартную регулярку, но даже сделать обработку уже измененных ссылок с `<a href`

Сейчас регулярка выглядит вот так, пока пытаюсь добавить только `nowollow` без замены `url` на внутренние, и то не получается

```
$ret = preg_replace("#(href=.*[^(mysite\.ru)])#is"," rel=\"nofollow\" href=$1", $ret);
```

Но обрабатывает только первую ссылку в тексте и только ту, в которой есть `mysite.ru`. А мне нужно обрабатывать все и те, в которых нет `mysite.ru`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

1. Я бы вам посоветовал не вторгаться неподсредственно в исходный код форума, изменяя родную регулярку, лучшим будет решение подключить внешний файл/модуль/класс унаследнованный от родного, в котором будет реализовано ваше поведение.
2. Задача которую Вы решаете достаточно распространенная, скорее всего вам стоит поискать уже готовый плагин/модуль для решения данной задачи

Как реализовать пункты 1, 2 - вам лучше смотреть на ресурсах, на которых задают вопросы по теме  конкретно того движка форума, который вы используете, либо оставить на этом же ресурсе соответствующий вопрос, указав при этом свой движек форума.

В общем же случае задача решается в несколько независимых этапов, например:

- Находим с помощью исходной регулярки все ссылки
- С помощью функции https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php выделяем из ссылки домен.
- Ну а дальше уже ваша логика по замене одних урлов на другие

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так или на основе этого.

```
$url = 'http://mysite.ru/?redirect='; //твой скрипт переадрисации

$ret = '
[url=http://yandex.ru]yandex[/url]
[url=http://google.ru]google[/url]
[url=http://ru.stackoverflow.com/]stackoverflow[/url]
[url=http://кириллица.рф/]кириллица[/url]
';

$ret = preg_replace('#\[url=([:/а-яёa-z0-9-.]+)\]([а-яёa-z0-9. ,\"-]+)\[/url\]#ius', '<a href="' . $url . '$1" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">$2</a>', $ret);

print_r($ret);
```